# SharePoint Online - Incomplete Search Results within Views

Tags: list-view, search-results

I have a List, which when searched in the default All Items view, yields results correctly. If you are in a different View however and the record searched for does not match the View filters, it does not return in the results. Even clicking to include hidden items when prompted yields no result.

I understand the filters are performing as designed but is there any way to force results to show without being in the All items view?

We want users in the habit of viewing the list based on their specific Location View, but it would be helpful for search to show results that are from other locations without having to jump between views.

Thanks!

Comment: I think there is a flaw in your logic.  If you want your users to get in the habit of using their Location View, then they should have to "go somewhere else" when they need to find files that don't belong to their location.  Otherwise, what is the point of limiting their view?  If you want them to have files from other locations intermixed with the results from their own location, then you don't really need a limited view.

Comment: @willman - I don't necessarily disagree but this is how the client wants it. I didn't expound earlier but basically salespeople are spread across 18 locations. Each location might hold or sell a piece of equipment from any other location. Each location's view shows active transactions for that location, but before requesting any specific item, the salesperson needs to ensure it is not already part of an active transaction with another location. Hence the global search before limiting to a specific location view. It's cumbersome but works the way the client desires.

Comment: all of my research leads me to believe search will not return records that don't meet the View filter criteria, but I wanted to ask to be sure I didn't miss anything.